# What is the best way to find postion (i, j) of 1's in matrix of zeros and ones?

Tags: python

Example

```py
[ 0 0 1,
  1 0 1,
  0 1 0 ]
```

Returned postions: `(1,3) ,(2,1) ,(2,3),(3,2)`

Comment: Use a nested `for` loop?

Comment: Do you mean your 'matrix' to be a list of strings or an actual 2D matrix? If you're hoping people are going to propose answers, you need to make your starting data clear.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please re-take the intro tour, especially [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Simply dumping your assignment on us with no attempt on your part, is not acceptable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

x=np.array([ [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1 ,0 ]])
res=np.argwhere(x==1)
print(x,res, sep="\n")
```

Outputs:

```py
[[0 0 1]
 [1 0 1]
 [0 1 0]]
[[0 2]
 [1 0]
 [1 2]
 [2 1]]
```

Some useful reference:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html